# How do I stop Gameranger from killing the game process?

Tags: gameranger

I use Gameranger to play online games like Age Of Empires 3. The problem that I'm facing is that when a problem in my connection occurs like a momentary disconnection (less than 10 seconds), Gameranger kills the game process. I don't know why it does that. Within that 10 seconds the game would normally reconnect automatically and I could continue playing, but Gameranger doesn't care that and it kills the process.

How can I stop it from doing that?

Comment: I had no idea momentaneous was a real word. O_O

Comment: @MatthewRead lol, I'm a spanish speaker so I invent new english words occasionally ;D

Comment: Just kill the gameranger process during this delay. If you dont kill him, he will kill you:)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Gameranger is causing you issues, your best bet is to contact Gameranger support at this [link](http://www.gameranger.com/support/game/).  It appears this is the intended behavior of the application, so your only recourse is to contact them directly if you're unhappy with it.

Comment: Thanks, i write in their forum the same question, and apparently is the "normal behaviour". I put a suggestion of making this a seteable option, I hope to be heard.

Comment: ... Geez. And people use this piece of software why?